# Color of a Metal's Threshold Wavelength?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, visible-light, photons, photoelectric-effect

How do I find the color of the threshold wavelength if the metal has a threshold wavelength of $\mathrm{6.5\times 10^{-7}m}$? I know that converts down to $\mathrm{650\ nm}$, but can I still use the visible color spectrum's wavelengths to find the color or is it different for metal?

Comment: Hi Mia. If you're interested in finding colors, then there are many online calculators like [this one](http://rohanhill.com/tools/WaveToRGB/) ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The metal's threshold wavelength is a wavelength of light. So yes, you would use a chart converting wavelengths of light to the color to identify it. For some metals, the threshold wavelength is not visible light; it might be ultraviolet. But whatever chart you're using would identify the wavelength you have as either ultraviolet or visible, and which color it is.